# scrollbar is not in visible area (width more than 100%)

Tags: html, css, html-table, scroll, scrollbar

I have a div which is more than 100% (width of table). The problem now is that I can't see the scrollbar for vertical scrolling, obviously. Can I adjust the position of the scrollbar?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.abc {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="abc">
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>    
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the `overflow` on the container only, as in the below snippet:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/*.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.abc {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  overflow: auto;
}*/

.abc {
  width: calc(100% + 50px);
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  overflow :auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="abc">
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>
    abc<br>    
  </div>
</div>
```